# Python: While loop inside a for loop only running for the first instance of for variable

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

So here's my problem: I have a `for` loop with a variable `k` running from 1 to 31. Inside the `for` loop there is a `while` loop that seemingly only runs for the very first `k` and no others.

```
from numpy import exp

a = 0.0
N = 1
x = 0.1

def f(t):
    return exp(-t**2)

def int_trap(x,N):
    h = (x-a)/N
    s = 0.5*f(a) + 0.5*f(x)
    for i in range(1,N):
        s += f(a + i*h)
    return h*s

new_value = 1.0
old_value = 0.0

for k in range(1,11):
    x = k/10
    while abs(new_value - old_value) > 10**-6:
        old_value = new_value
        N = N*2
        new_value = int_trap(x,N)
        print(N,'\t',x,'\t',abs(new_value - old_value))
    print(x)
```

The `print(x)` at the end is there to confirm that that the code is running through the `k`'s.

And here's the output:

```
2        0.1     0.900373598036
4        0.1     3.09486672713e-05
8        0.1     7.73536466929e-06
16       0.1     1.93372859864e-06
32       0.1     4.83425115119e-07
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1.0
```

Comment: You `while` loop checks `abs(new_value - old_value)` against `10**-6` - the last time it prints you had `4.83425115119e-07` which is smaller than the `10**-6` so it won't run again.

Comment: Are you using python2? Division of integers gives an integer in python2, so your problem is most likely in the line `x = k/10`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki The output of the `print` suggests python3.

Answer (score 3):

The `for` loop runs fine through all `k` values. It doesn't run through the `while` loop, perhaps because you don't reset the `new_value` and `old_value` variables inside the `for` loop. If we add some things to print to the original loop:

```
for k in range(1,11):
    x = k/10
    while abs(new_value - old_value) > 10**-6:
        old_value = new_value
        N = N*2
        new_value = int_trap(x,N)
        print(N,'\t',x,'\t',abs(new_value - old_value), 'In while for x={} and k={}'.format(x, k))
    print(x, '\tThis is me completing the loop for k=', k)
```

We see that it is correctly running for all `k` values:

```
2    0.1     0.900373598036 In while for x=0.1 and k=1
4    0.1     3.09486672713e-05 In while for x=0.1 and k=1
8    0.1     7.73536466929e-06 In while for x=0.1 and k=1
16   0.1     1.93372859864e-06 In while for x=0.1 and k=1
32   0.1     4.83425115119e-07 In while for x=0.1 and k=1
0.1     This is me completing the loop for k= 1
0.2     This is me completing the loop for k= 2
0.3     This is me completing the loop for k= 3
0.4     This is me completing the loop for k= 4
0.5     This is me completing the loop for k= 5
0.6     This is me completing the loop for k= 6
0.7     This is me completing the loop for k= 7
0.8     This is me completing the loop for k= 8
0.9     This is me completing the loop for k= 9
1.0     This is me completing the loop for k= 10
```

So try the following:

```
for k in range(1,11):
    x = k/10
    new_value = 1.0
    old_value = 0.0
    while abs(new_value - old_value) > 10**-6:
        old_value = new_value
        N = N*2
        new_value = int_trap(x,N)
        print(N,'\t',x,'\t',abs(new_value - old_value), 'In while for x={} and k={}'.format(x, k))
    print(x, '\tThis is me completing the loop for k=', k)
```